# Running Docker in WSL2, facing git login problem

Tags: git, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run docker in WSL2. I installed Ubuntu and it starts fine, I configured my git access with ssh key stored in .ssh and tested the access with `ssh my-git-server.com` and it gives the welcome information.
I also installed docker desktop for windows and selected WSL integration.

I did docker login to the git server for the docker, it was also successful.

I can start docker-compose and get the docker running.

When I tried to run cmake in docker, I was hit with login request:

`Username for 'https://"my-git-server".com':`

and I can use my username and password to login, but then it will pop up request for that again.

I tried to add docker credential helper with no help for this issue.
`git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe"` doesn't help this issue either, because docker image doesn't have the c drive mounted, doesn't have git binaries or docker binaries either.

Answer (score 1):

Some action in your cmake build tries to access your repo through `https`, not `ssh`.

You may either :

1. spot that action and change the way your repository gets cloned,
2. or add a [`insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) configuration entry within your docker environment :

```
git config --global \
        url."git@my-git-server.com:".insteadOf my-git-server.com/
```

Comment: This is also what I found useful, now I don't have that request coming up all the time! Thanks!